# Apple HLSCatelog could not download (Offline) live video - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, offline, wowza

I am trying to save(offline download) the streaming video to device.
For streaming using [Wowza Streaming engine](https://www.wowza.com/) I could stream and download offline a vod (video on demand mp4 using m3u8 url).
But, I failed to save the live streaming. I am able to stream the live video but, download not happening.
Here the app code [Apple HLS Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HLSCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) App could not download live video.

Any help, highly appreciated.

Comment: I wasn't even able to stream. I only got the first frame of the stream. Could you please post an update if you have found a solution. I also am using Wowza, and I tried the Apple HLS Catalog example, and my own implementation.

Comment: for stream u can directly play uisng AVPlayer. video format m3u8